# How do I get my application to choose between two app.config files?

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I want to create two app.config files and let the user decide which one to use by a command line argument. How do I get my application to use one .config or the other within my code?

I am using a Settings file which is set by the config file. There are two possible configurations and it would be easier if the user could just type ">myprogram -live" or ">myprogram -test" and the program select which config file to load from. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy two of your exe files with different names:

```
myprogram.live.exe
myprogram.live.config
myprogram.test.exe
myprogram.test.config
```

And then you can choose to start `myprogram.live` or `myprogram.test`.